# Как убрать отображение товара, которого нет в наличии WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Есть товар, в котором два цвета и три размера

В вариациях товара настроил так:
**Зеленый** - Размер с любым значение
**Черный** - Размер с любым значением + S (нет в наличии)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Но на сайте это отображается как три разных товара, не понимаю, как это исправить**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По умолчанию отсутствующее на складе не выводится.

Comment: SeVlad, где это можно настроить, через код?

Comment: Вероятно был не прав на счёт "по умолчанию". Возможно это всё же настраивается. См ответ.

Comment: Я перечитал вопрос. Сорри, я откометил только проблему с выводом отсутствующих (что в заголовке и спрашивалось). А вот почему у тебя выводится три товара вместо одного - тут либо ты что-то не так сделал либо кто-то косячит - какой-то плагин или темы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Настройка "не показать закончившееся" находится в "Настройка WC"-Товары-Запасы

[image]